# List of well-maintained `conda` channels

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

`conda` takes the `-c` argument to specify which channel to install packages from.

Apart from the `default` channel, are all other channels a flat mess of user-created content, or are some channels widely regarded as professionally maintained and robust?

Is the `intel` channel actually from the chip manufacturer, or can any old Joe Bloggs create a channel called `intel`?

[anaconda.org](http://anaconda.org) seems to list user-created channels without any kind of recommendations as to purpose or quality.

Where can I find a curated lists of channels?

- Which are commonly well regarded (and why)
- Which channels serve which purposes
- New / interesting channels

Answer (score 15):

In my experience, the two largest and best-maintained channels are `defaults` and `conda-forge`. Conda Forge (who run the `conda-forge` channel) are also an organization that has [governance](https://conda-forge.org/docs/orga/governance.html), [code of conduct](https://conda-forge.org/docs/orga/governance.html#code-of-conduct), and other things that mark it as a well-run open-source project. It is also part of NumFOCUS, which is a non-profit in the US that supports open-source scientific software. (Disclaimer: I am also part of an organization that is under the NumFOCUS umbrella, and I maintain several packages for conda-forge, although I am not involved in any governance decisions for Conda Forge).

As far as I know, the `intel` channel is indeed maintained by the chip maker. Namespace squatting could certainly be a problem; I don't work for Anaconda Inc. so I don't know how they handle those cases.

As far as I know, there is not a curated list of channels. Packages where the maintainers use their own channel tend to list that in their install instructions, and some fields have their own channels (e.g., [bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/)), so people in that field tend to know about that channel.

Answer (score 0):

intel channel do come from the chip manufacturer.

Here are my answers to the questions:

1. intel is a common channel for optimized version of frameworks and packages. eg: tensorflow, caffe. Also there are certain packages that is there only in certain channels. for eg: ffmpeg comes only from menpo channel of anaconda
2. Any channel would have a set of packages it offers, each package will have its own functionality. So it is better to infer the purpose from the packages rather than channels
3. https://anaconda.org/search?q=channel will give you some channels. But I strongly recommend you to see it from the perspective of functionality which boils down to packages in channels and not channels themselves.

Comment: You don't give any curated list of channels. (1) You ignored this. (2) is like saying it's better to infer what a program does by reading the source rather than the manual. (3) The link you give only lists channels with `channel` in their name, which is far from helpful.

Comment: Have never come across  such a curated list maintained anywhere. (2) The intention was not to read source, but to point out the fact that a single channel may have packages pertaining to different purposes & may not be generalizable. May be it is two different perspective. What I usually do is, I first search my requirement, find the right package for it and then install. I bother about multiple channels only if I have more than one option and I could find a difference between the two options. (3) Sorry about that. Could not find a better option to search based on channel in anaconda.org.

Answer (score 0):

Only two channels are enough, that are "Default" channel and "anaconda" channel. Remove all other if getting error as "unavailableinvalidchannel: the channel is not accessible or is invalid."

Answer (score -1):

I recommend pypi. (I think it was pypi, but maybe conda-forge.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Please avoid the impression to ask a question instead of answering. You can e.g. phrase a conditional answer like "If your problem is ... then the solution is ... because ... ." Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35775605)